# Apache: Slow File Download, No Errors

Tags: apache-2.2

New day, new problem.

Apache is working great. Except, when I download files or images it takes ages. Max speed is now 30KB/s .. it was about 300KB/s

I tried downloading via SFTP but the same.

I contacted my host, but what else can I do to analyze the problem? I checked server logs already, I fixed all problems.

Answer (score 0):

The network between you and your host is either horribly slow or horribly congested. There's likely nothing you can do about it.